# SQLite: difference between successful and failed query?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Sorry for the vague question but as the topic states, how do I tell if a query succeeded or failed given I only have the query result?

I compared a successful and a failed query when trying to fetch a single row and the only difference I noticed was that the one that did manage to fetch the row returned with **mCount = 1** while the other one returned with **mCount = 0**.

**Edit:**
The method that return the cursor.

```
public Cursor getElement(int elementID){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_UN_ID, COLUMN_NAME_UN_NAME}, COLUMN_NAME_UN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(elementID)}, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: What language are you using SQLite in?

Comment: You should paste a piece of code representing how do you execute query and how do you read results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query contains syntax errors, you'll get an exception.

If the query doesn't match any records, you'll get an empty cursor.

Check the result value of `moveTo...()` to see whether the cursor points to a valid row after the move. The canonical way of looping through a cursor is

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    // do something with row data
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

You can also use `cursor.getCount()` to get the number of rows but from performance point of view it's not as efficient as the do-while above.

`SQLiteDatabase` `query()` won't return `null` so checking for `!= null` is not necessary.

Comment: Hmm, so I can just check if moveToFirst() returns false to check if the cursor failed?

Comment: If by failing you mean "does not contain any rows", then yes.